# highcharts world map not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to use highcharts for creating a world map .The map is not visible but zoom icon and map scale  is visible.
There is no error on the console.

[Please check the demo here]

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.11.0/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/mapdata/custom/world-highres2

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/modules/map.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div  id= "container1" style="height:500px;min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px;margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">


window.onload = function() {
$.ajax({
    test();
});
    };
function test(){
var UsGeo = [{
       "hc-key": "fo",
       "value": 0
   },
     {
         "hc-key": "um",
         "value": 1
     },
     {
         "hc-key": "us",
         "value": 2
     },
     {
         "hc-key": "jp",
         "value": 3
     }];

 $('#container1').highcharts('Map', {

       title: {
           text: 'Highmaps basic demo'
       },

       subtitle: {
           text: 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world-highres2.js">World, Miller projection, very high resolution</a>'
       },

       mapNavigation: {
           enabled: true,
           buttonOptions: {
               verticalAlign: 'bottom'
           }
       },

       colorAxis: {
           min: 0
       },

       series: [{
           data: UsGeo,
           mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world-highres2'],
           joinBy: 'hc-key',
           name: 'Random data',
           states: {
               hover: {
                   color: '#BADA55'
               }
           },
           dataLabels: {
               enabled: true,
               format: '{point.name}'
           }
       }]
   });
   });
</script>  
}
```

Comment: The map is visible for me in the jsfiddle. What browser are you using?

Comment: Yep, visible for me too on Chrome, Firefox and IE. Browser version?

Comment: @Oliver   its visible in fiddle but when i tried to do same its not displaying the map..I am using Chrome

Comment: I checked in chrome,its visible, Check in your own code

Comment: @Iquery I got the isssu probably. why you are using highstock.js? use updates libs ,highmap can be used as per the examples in demo

Comment: @NishithChaturvedi Thank you so much.. it did solve the problem.but i am creating some more charts on same page using highstocks.js.
If i use only the mentioned js files in fiddle ,other graphs give error.Any solution to it.

Comment: can u share your comlete code with fiddle ? including other graphs you are using

Comment: @NishithChaturvedi  please find the demo in the fiddle link below:

[link] (http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/)

Comment: @Iquery that's a simple pie chart demo , I was asking your your actual code so that ,it could be analysed .

Comment: Also wrap your code in $(function(){ // here })

Comment: @NishithChaturvedi  i am dynamically loading data into the same pie charts on same page...do u still want to have a look at the actual code.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems , you need to call highstock and other libs from CDN not any intermediate build from GIT .

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
```

[See highmap working with pie chart using highstock](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/69201zz1/1/)